# Python 3.4 email to multiple receivers throws an ERROR

Tags: email, python-3.x, message, account

I'm writing a script to send an email to more than one email account, but not able, yet.

It works as it is below, but if I set `receivers='xxx@xxx.com','yyy@yyy.com'` it won't work, it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'.
```

How can I set `receivers=`?

```
def send_email (out_file):

    sender = 'xxx@xxx.com'
    receivers = 'xxx@xxx.com'
    email_pass = 'aaaa'

    filematch=re.findall('NE.*\.txt',out_file.name)

    subject = ("NEXXXX_price_update")
    message = ("The following file was forwarded to your ftp account %s "  %filematch)

    msg = 'Subject: %s\n%s' %(subject, message)


    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',0)
        smtpObj.login(receivers, email_pass)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg)

        print ("Successfully sent email")

    except SMTPException:        

        print ("email NOT successful")
        print(SMTPException.__cause__)        

        smtpObj.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign wrongly

```
receivers='xxx@xxx.com','yyy@yyy.com'
```

You suppose to assign as a `tuple` or `list`, not sure 100% which.

Give a try:

```
receivers=('xxx@xxx.com','yyy@yyy.com')
```

or

```
receivers=['xxx@xxx.com','yyy@yyy.com']
```